# Show that unique mapping from Q to ordered field exists

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

In my analysis textbook I had to prove that there exists a mapping $f: \mathbb{Q} \to K$ (Q is the set of rational numbers, K is an ordered field) such that for all $a,b \in Q$ we have:

1. $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$
2. $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$
3. $a < b$ iff $f(a) < f(b)$.

I was able to construct such a mapping. The book states that this mapping is unique. How would I prove that?

Thank you!

**EDIT (Proof using Wojowu's hint)**:

Let $g:Q \to K$ be another mapping with the properties 1-3.

For $1\in Q$ we have $g(1)=g(1*1)=g(1)g(1)$ and thus $g(1)=1$.

We also have $g(0)=g(0+0)=g(0)+g(0)$ and thus $g(0)=0$.

For any integer $m$ we therefore get $g(m)+g(-m)=g(m-m)=g(0)=0$ and thus $g(-m)=-g(m)$.

Thus, for every positive integer $m$ we get

$$g(m)=g\left(\sum_{i=1}^m 1\right)=\sum_{i=1}^m g(1)=\sum_{i=1}^m 1.$$

If $m$ is a negative integer, we obtain

$$g(m)=g(-(-m))=-g(-m)=-\sum_{i=1}^{-m} 1.$$

The same holds for the mapping $f$ which means, for any integer $m$ we have $f(m)=g(m)$.

One more property that holds for $f,g$ and any $a\in Q$ with $a\neq 0$.

We have $g(a)*g(a^{-1})=g(a*a^{-1})=g(1)=1$ and therefore $g(a^{-1})=g(a)^{-1}$.

Now, we can prove that $f=g$.

Let $a\in Q$ be arbitrary. Then $a=\frac{p}{q}$ for integers $p,q$ and $q\gt 0$.

We have

$$f(a)=f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=f(p)f(q^{-1})=f(p)f(q)^{-1}$$

and

$$g(a)=g\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=g(p)g(q^{-1})=g(p)g(q)^{-1}$$.

Because of $f(p)=g(p)$ and $f(q)^{-1}=g(q)^{-1}$ we obtain

$$f(a)=g(a)$$.

Thus, we have shown that $f=g$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please note that proper formatting is expected (we did it for you); for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @mlc, please use blackboard bold.

Comment: Hint: where does $1$ have to go? If you know where $1$ goes, where does every other integer go?

Comment: Thank you very much for the welcome! Apologies for not formatting in the first place.

Comment: @Wojwu: I think, I got what you meant. I edited my post and included the proof.

Comment: @Wojowu: Thank you very much for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: conditions 1) and 2) imply that $f$ is a ring homomorphism. Condition 3) implies that it is nonzero. Show that there is a unique nonzero homomorphism from ${\bf Q}$ to a field of characteristic $0$. (To do that, you can note that a nonzero homomorphism between fields is automatically unital.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The problem is, the book covered no homomorphisms. So, I don't know how to use your hint. But, I will come back to it when I will have the necessary background for using your hint.

Comment: @Sebastian: You know what an ordered field is, but not what a homomorphism is? What is the course you're taking?

Comment: It is an introductory analysis textbook. It doesn't cover homomorphisms.